# Click a button in CefSharp browser in Windows Forms

Tags: javascript, c#, html, winforms, cefsharp

I'm trying to click a button on a webpage (kahoot.it), and I already know that I probably need to use Javascript for that which is fine, as long as it stays with 1 line of JavaScript because that's easy to implement in WinForms. I don't have much information on the button,
only:

```
<button type="submit" value="Submit" class="enter-button__EnterButton-sc-1o9b9va-0 kxpxeu" data-functional-selector="join-game-pin"><span>Enter</span></button>
```

Could you guys please help? There's only one button on the page, maybe that helps.

Comment: Do you mean you want to click on the button which is in the web page, using C# code?

Comment: Start by reading https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#1-how-do-you-call-a-javascript-method-from-net

Comment: @RezaAghaei Yes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to write a piece of javascript code and run it when the page loaded.

**Run script after page loaded**

To run the code after the page loaded, you can use [`ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPageLoaded`](http://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPageLoaded.htm) method or you can handle [`FrameLoadEnd`](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/E_CefSharp_WinForms_ChromiumWebBrowser_FrameLoadEnd.htm) or [`LoadingStateChanged`](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/75.1.x/html/E_CefSharp_WinForms_ChromiumWebBrowser_LoadingStateChanged.htm).

**DOM manipulation - find element, set value, click on button**

For the javascript code, you can use any of the available javascript functions. for example find the element using `getElemenetsByName`, `getElementsByTagName` or `getElementById`.

After you found the element, you can set its `value` or for example for a button you can click on it by calling its `click()` method.

### CefSharp Example - Browse a URL, fill an input and click on a button

The following code, adds a `ChromiumWebBrowser` control to a `Form`. Then it browses [google](https://www.google.com) and fill the search box with a text and clicks on the search button:

```
//using CefSharp;
//using CefSharp.WinForms;
ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.google.com/");
    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    Controls.Add(browser);
    var script = @"
            document.getElementsByName('q')[0].value = 'CefSharp C# Example';
            document.getElementsByName('btnK')[0].click();
        ";
    browser.ExecuteScriptAsyncWhenPageLoaded(script);
}
```

**Example 2**

In the following example, using `ExecuteScriptAsync` you can fill the search box with a text and clicks on the search button programmatically:

```
//using CefSharp;
//using CefSharp.WinForms;
ChromiumWebBrowser browser;
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnLoad(e);
    browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.google.com/");
    browser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    Controls.Add(browser);
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var script = @"
        document.getElementsByName('q')[0].value = 'CefSharp C# Example';
        document.getElementsByName('btnK')[0].click();
    ";
    browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);
}
```

***Note:*** In your case, for [kahoot.it](https://kahoot.it), the script should be:

```
var script = @"
        document.getElementById('game-input').value = '123';
        document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].click();
    ";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! How would I run the same script but trigger it when clicking a button on the WinForms?

Comment: You're welcome. Handle `Click` event of the button. Then in the event handler,  write `var script = ...;` then `browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);`.

Comment: Thank you!! Now I have just one more question. The site doesn't seem to recognize the input in the textbox. When I run the code, it gives me an error that is given when the textbox is empty, however when I manually type it, it gives me another error (Which is okay, and the result I want to have).

Comment: The `CefSharp API Doc` links as a bit all over the place, three different versions are referenced, none of which is the current version `75.1.x`. Also one of the links is for the `OffScreen` version, not `WinForms`. For general reference http://cefsharp.github.io/api/ contains a list of all `API` docs, use the version that matches (Docs are version specific).

Comment: @amaitland Thanks for checking the links. Feel free to correct them if you know the correct links (I appreciate your contribution). I also will check them as soon as I can :)

Comment: @RezaAghaei Links fixed. Overall a very detailed answer :+1:

Comment: Can we open another Windows Form by clicking on a button (button1_Click in above example) which is part of chromium web? Is this possible with CefSharp?

Comment: what about getting the value of input element using cefsharp?
because variable in c# is different context with the JS context am i right... @RezaAghaei?

Comment: @gumuruh I expect you are able to use `EvaluateScriptAsync` to execute a piece of js code which returns value of an input.

Answer (score 1):

Changing **Target Framework** version to 4.7.2 from 4.0 fixed for me
[True Target Framework Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J31hR.png)