# CefSharp button click

Tags: javascript, vb.net, html-agility-pack, cefsharp

I have a problem with clicking the button on the webpage with CefSharp Browser.

- WinForms + CefSharp Browser
- I load the page (Twitter) with CefSharp Browser
- I load the HTML source from CefSharp Browser into HtmlAgilityPack
- I find the buttons using HtmlAgilityPack

And thats where I got stuck, I was unable to write a proper JS script to execute the clicks.

```
Dim WebDoc As New HtmlDocument
WebDoc.LoadHtml(HTMLSource)

Dim TweetList As HtmlNodeCollection = WebDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//section[@aria-labelledby='accessible-list-1']//div[@data-testid='tweet']")

Dim ListofButtons As New List(Of HtmlNode)
For Each Tweet In TweetList
    ListofButtons.Add(Tweet.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@role='button']"))
Next
For Each Button In ListofButtons
    'As I understand I need to call Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("button.click();")
Next
```

I tried a few different things I found around the web but they didn't work, and all the tutorials are with ids and class names none of which I can use in this case.

Comment: Could I ask you why you use VB ?
Maybe you could use C#. Bcs there it is easy + a bigger community which can help you with problems :)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59230233/click-a-button-in-cefsharp-browser-in-windows-forms

Comment: @Deniz Because that's what I learned first, and it's basically the same thing, it's just written a bit differently. As far as that thread, those aren't useful to me because  it doesn't have any simple elements to select. Forgetting about all the other levels, how would I select the div with role='button'?

Comment: @Deniz Basically, I need html//section[@aria-labelledby='accessible-list-1']//div[@data-testid='tweet']//div[@role='button'], where // is unlimited depth of search. The xpath has a couple of dozen elements.

Comment: The link i already posted has the right JavaScript-Code.
The JavaScript-Code should work for you aswell :)
But I also need to learn how to select a button without a name, iD or a TagName which is multiple times on the page.
If i know it i will tell you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I did it is:

```
Browser.EvaluateScriptAsync("document.querySelectorAll(""section[aria-labelledby='accessible-list-1'] div[data-testid='tweet'] div[role='button'])"").forEach(button=>button.click())")
```

Comment: @deniz here is how I did it.

Comment: Ah ok nice. Will try it out now ! :)
ForEach? So you press every button on the page?^^

Comment: @Deniz Every selected button, yes.

Comment: I don't understand how you select it.
@CruleD How would it look like if you select here:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/buttons/
the blue Large button ? :)

Comment: @deniz You can do it multiple ways,for example: just (""button"") for all or (""button[class='btn btn-success]"") for one.

Comment: Ah ok, I do it like that: script = @"document.getElementsByName('btnK')[0].click();"; BTW. do you know how to get an active element ? I want to read out the inner and/or outer HTML just of that active element: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62084104/cefsharp-get-a-part-from-a-source-code-of-a-selected-and-or-mouse-hovered-elemen

Comment: I'm not familiar with JS, I found this out by combining multiple answers. "section[aria-labelledby='accessible-list-1'] div[data-testid='tweet']" is like "section[@aria-labelledby='accessible-list-1']//div[@data-testid='tweet']" in htmlagilitypack. So based on that I would do it with "input[name='q']"