# How to perform click on button on web page?

Tags: javascript, c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I'd like to click programmatically on the button when it appears on the web page, is there a way to do it?

here is the button, it has no ID, only this;

```
<div class="VotingButtons"><button class="VotingButton VotingButton--upvote btn-white" type="button">Like</button>
```

Here are more information about the button:

```
<div class="VotingWrapper VotingWrapper--isBlocking"><p class="VotingWrapper__text"><strong>Do you like this image?</strong></p><div class="VotingButtons"><button class="VotingButton VotingButton--upvote btn-white" type="button">Like</button><button class="VotingButton VotingButton--downvote btn-white" type="button"><span class="VotingButton__text--hideOnMobile">Dislike</span></button></div></div>
```

I tried to use this code but it doesn't work:

```
private async void Btn_GoToDirectly_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        var script = @"
document.getElementsByClassName('VotingButton VotingButton--upvote btn-white')[0].click();
browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);
    ";
            browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementByClassName('VotingButton VotingButton--upvote btn-white').click()");
```

Comment: From [tagging help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging): _The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title._ Quoting that page with formats you've tried to use: _"Avoid inserting tags into titles in any of the following formats:"_ _"[tag]: [question title]"_ and _"[question title] -- [tag] [tag] [tag]"_.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Click a button in CefSharp browser in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59230233/click-a-button-in-cefsharp-browser-in-windows-forms)

Comment: Make sure your JavaScript works in DevTools. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Trouble-Shooting#javascript-debugging you should remove ExecuteScriptAsync from your JavaScript.

Comment: @amaitland unfortunately, no...

Answer (score 0):

the string you have for the variable script has `getElementsByClassName` and uses the result at index 0 (seems correct),
but the script you actually run has `getElementByClassName` , singular, which doesn't exist (and no indexer of course).. did you try to run the script variable?

```
    string script = @"document.getElementsByClassName('VotingButton VotingButton--upvote btn-white')[0].click();"
    browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);
```

this does everything but the cefsharp code- but if you have something like this in javascript, the code in `script` should work through cefsharp...

```js
let like= function(){
    console.log("like");
};

let trigger= function(){
console.log("trigger");
document.getElementsByClassName('VotingButton VotingButton--upvote btn-white')[0].click();
};
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="VotingWrapper VotingWrapper--isBlocking">
<p class="VotingWrapper__text">
<strong>Do you like this image?</strong>
</p>
<div class="VotingButtons">
<button onclick="like()" class="VotingButton VotingButton--upvote btn-white" type="button">Like</button>
<button class="VotingButton VotingButton--downvote btn-white" type="button">
<span class="VotingButton__text--hideOnMobile">Dislike</span>
</button>
</div>
</div>
<button onclick="trigger()" type="button">Trigger</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @audzyy i tried but it doesn't work... also, the button text is "Like", I'm not sure how to target it

Comment: to find the text you could use something like `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button'))
  .find(btn => btn.textContent === 'Like');`

Comment: also, did you notice I modified what you posted a little bit in the script string? so it doesnt have the  `browser.ExecuteScriptAsync` part in the string

Comment: Tried everything, copied your code and all, but no luck...

Comment: do you get to this function : Btn_GoToDirectly_Click ?

Comment: it is the button that I click to perform this javascript. Also, I edited my question, I added more information about the button, I don't know if it helps...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223327/discussion-between-renato-lulic-and-audzzy).

Answer (score -2):

you can use selenium，

Nuget import Selenium.RC，Selenium.Support，Selenium.WebDriver,

```
 using (IWebDriver driver = new OpenQA.Selenium.IE.InternetExplorerDriver())
     {
         driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.xxurl.com");  
         driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("VotingButton VotingButton--upvote btn-white")).Click();
     }
```